# How do I insert a blank page into a PDF with ghostscript or pdftk?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, pdftk

I have a PDF file that needs a blank page inserted into it every so often. The pattern is unpredictable, so I need a command that will allow me to fit one in wherever necessary.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From http://blog.chewearn.com/2008/12/18/rearrange-pdf-pages-with-pdftk/

```
pdftk A=src.pdf B=blank.pdf cat A1 B1 A2-end output res.pdf
```

Hope you like this script, just save it as `pdfInsertBlankPageAt.sh`, add execute permissions, and run.

`./pdfInsertBlankPageAt 5 src.pdf res.pdf`

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 3 ]
then
  echo "Usage example: ./pdfInsertBlankPageAt 5 src.pdf res.pdf"
  exit $E_BADARGS
else
  pdftk A=$2 B=blank.pdf cat A1-$(($1-1)) B1 A$1-end output $3
fi
```

`cat A1 B1 A2-end` means that the output file will contain the first page of document A (`src.pdf`) followed by the first page of document B (`blank.pdf`) followed by the rest (pages 2 to end) of document B.  This operation is called concatenation, Linux `cat` is very often used to display text, but it is interesting when used with more than one argument.

To create `blank.pdf`, see [How do I create a blank PDF from the command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277892/can-i-create-a-blank-pdf-from-the-command-line)

Comment: I suggest adding a small explanation what the command does, what effect it has (e.g. where the blank page is inserted). Also you could add a convenient way how to create a pdf file with only a blank page in it.

Comment: I found today the following command to create a blank page using the command line: `echo "" | ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE=a4 - pageblanche.pdf`

Comment: When trying this to insert a blank page a the beginning of the document (Page 1) i get the following error: Error: Unexpected range end; expected a page
   number or legal keyword, here: A1
   Exiting.
Errors encountered.  No output created.
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone just looking to add a single blank page to the end of a PDF, I used the already linked question [How do I create a blank PDF from the command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277892/can-i-create-a-blank-pdf-from-the-command-line) to create a `blank.pdf` file and merge it with my existing pdf using `pdfunite`:

```
pdfunite input.pdf blank.pdf output.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

If using pdfjam is an option:

```bash
pdfjam --outfile output.pdf input.pdf "-20,{},21-"
```

In pdfjam, `{}` inside range specifications is interpreted as a blank page, so this command inserts a blank page between pages 20 and 21.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the steps I used to have blank page after every page of my Pdf file with Pdftk in Ubuntu

1-Install pdftk if you haven't already

```
sudo apt-get install pdftk
```

2-Create a blank PDF file named blank.pdf. You can use the convert command from the ImageMagick package to create a blank image and then convert it to PDF. Run the following commands:

```
sudo apt install imagemagick
convert -size 595x842 xc:white blank.jpg
convert blank.jpg blank.pdf
```

if you got security policy error, open the policy.xml file using a text editor with root privileges. For example, you can use the following command to open it with the nano editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
```

Change the value of the rights attribute from "none" to "read|write" for PDF. The modified line should look like this:

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />
```

3- Now navigate to the directory where your PDF file is located then use the following commands

```
pdftk input.pdf burst output burst_output%d.pdf
pdftk $(for f in burst_output*.pdf; do echo -n "$f blank.pdf "; done) cat output final.pdf
```

put the name of your input file instead of "input".

Now your final.pdf is ready!
You can delete the splitted pages after this.