# How do I create a blank PDF from the command line?

Tags: command-line, pdf

I recently needed a single blank PDF page (8.5" x 11" size) and realized that I didn't know how to make one from the command line.

Issuing `touch blank.pdf` produces an empty PDF *file*. Is there a command line tool that produces an empty PDF *page*?

Comment: Why do you need it? I have a printing package for emulating two-sided (duplex) printing on non-duplex printers. Doing this requires putting out an extra blank page when printing the even numbered pages for a job that has an odd page count. To do this, I just send a formfeed to lp. That does the trick without creating a blank page file, etc..

Comment: @Joe It's none of our business why Brian wants or needs this.

Comment: @IainHolder: I wish more SE users thought like you.

Comment: @IainHolder - I'm not trying to pry into the OP's business! I just wanted to suggest that if it's something like what I was doing, then there's another way to do it. Often things like this are xy problems (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so asking what the goal is can be quite appropriate.

Comment: I just read through the link above in detail. I didn't realize this was such a controversial  issue. TL;DR - if you know what you're doing, then you just want the answer to the question you asked. If you're not so well versed, you may have asked the wrong question and clarification of what the real issue is could help.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

`convert`, the ImageMagick utility used in Ketan's answer, also allows you to write something like

```
convert xc:none -page Letter a.pdf
```

or

```
convert xc:none -page A4 a.pdf
```

or (for horizontal A4 paper)

```
convert xc:none -page 842x595 a.pdf
```

[etc.](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#page), without creating an empty text file. @chbrown noticed that this creates a smaller pdf file.

"xc:" means "X Constant Image" but could really be thought of as "x canvas". It's a way to specify a single block of a color, in this case none. More info at http://imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#solid which is the "de facto" manual for ImageMagick. [supplemented with information from pipe] (Things like `pdf:a` can be used to explicitly declare the format of a file. `label:'some text'`, `gradient:`, `rose:` and `logo:`  seem to be other examples of special file formats.)

Anko suggested posting this modification as a separate answer, so I am doing it.

Comment: ImageMagick does not really have a useful manual. "xc:<foo>" means "X Constant Image" but could really be thought of as "x canvas". It's a way to specify a single block of a color, in this case _none_. More info at http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#solid which is the "de facto" manual for ImageMagick.

Comment: As a by-the-way, this also works with A4 instead of Letter, if you want sensible paper sizes.

Comment: @TRiG: Of course. I am sorry that I did not mention you in my edit, but in this case I had known it.

Comment: I changed this to the accepted answer since it's the one I put into my `~/bin`

Comment: Can this command be altered to produce a pdf file with n blank pages?

Comment: When running this command I got an error `convert-im6.q16: not authorized 'blank.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037`, but I found the solution here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081895/trouble-with-batch-conversion-of-png-to-pdf-using-convert  Posting here in case it helps anyone else who runs into the same issue.

Comment: @BartekChom Is it possible to create a file with multiple pages? Say 20 pages... Thanks.

Comment: Note that while ImageMagick's geometry argument accepts decimal values, they are [rounded](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/7.1.1-11/MagickCore/geometry.c#L330) to next whole number before they are written to the PDF file which can result in incorrect page sizes. This can be inspected with `pdfinfo` from poppler.

Answer (score 46):

Like the [smallest possible GIF](http://probablyprogramming.com/2009/03/15/the-tiniest-gif-ever), the smallest possible blank-page PDF needs to be worked out by hand, because it's so small that unnecessary-but-harmless bits of metadata become a significant part of the file size, and compression actually makes things *bigger*.  It also requires careful attention to the rules in the PDF specification about what bits of the file structure are and are not required.  (Did you know that page objects must contain a `/Resources` dictionary, even if it's empty, but are *not* required to include a `/Contents` stream?)

If you don't use PDF 1.5 object and cross-reference streams (which has the advantage that the file can be completely printable ASCII) I believe the best you can do is 317 bytes.  If copying and pasting, take note that there needs to be a trailing space on all four of the cross-reference table entries (the lines between `0 4` and `trailer<<...`), and that there is **not** supposed to be a final newline after the `%%EOF`.

```
%PDF-1.4
1 0 obj<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>>endobj
2 0 obj<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[3 0 R]>>endobj
3 0 obj<</Type/Page/MediaBox[0 0 612 792]/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<<>>>>endobj
xref
0 4
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000009 00000 n 
0000000052 00000 n 
0000000101 00000 n 
trailer<</Size 4/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
178
%%EOF
```

Replacing the cross-reference table with a manually crafted v1.5 cross-reference stream does make the file slightly smaller, at the price of its no longer being printable ASCII: 294 bytes.  (For the sake of readability, not to mention being able to type it in at all, the xref stream below has been hexdumped, but this is **not** reflected in its stream dictionary.  To recover a valid PDF you must either replace the hexdump with the corresponding raw binary bytes, or change `/Length 15` to `/Length 30/Filter/ASCIIHexDecode` and accept a file that is 328 bytes long.)

```
%PDF-1.5
1 0 obj<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>>endobj
2 0 obj<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[3 0 R]>>endobj
3 0 obj<</Type/Page/MediaBox[0 0 612 792]/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<<>>>>endobj
4 0 obj<</Type/XRef/Size 5/W[1 1 1]/Root 1 0 R/Length 15>>stream
0000ff01090001340001650001b200endstream endobj
startxref
178
%%EOF
```

I also experimented with wrapping objects 1 through 3 into an object stream, but this adds back more overhead than it saves, even when the stream is compressed.

A possible alternative formulation of the xref stream is

```
4 0 obj<</Type/XRef/Size 4/W[0 1 0]/Index[1 4]/Root 1 0 R/Length 4>>stream
091365b2endstream endobj
```

Sadly, despite the substantial savings in the length of the actual stream data, the additional `/Index[1 4]` eats up all but one byte of the savings.  Also, it is unclear to me whether you're allowed to leave object 0 completely out of the file.  (It's also unclear to me whether object 0 must have generation number -1.  If *that's* not required, you actually save more bytes with

```
4 0 obj<</Type/XRef/Size 5/W[1 1 0]/Root 1 0 R/Length 10>>stream
000001090134016501b2endstream endobj
```

.)

To change the paper size, replace `612 792` with the appropriate width and height, expressed in PostScript points (72 PostScript points = 1 U.S. inch or 25.4 millimeters).  For instance, `595 842` for A4.  You could embed this in a shell script that spits out a blank PDF of whatever paper size is desired; the only tricky part would be making sure that the `startxref` offset remained accurate even if the size of object 3 changed.

Comment: This might be a fun activity for http://codegolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: I posted to meta.codegolf to see if something like this would be well received: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8990/hand-crafting-a-pdf

Comment: While this is a nice solution to create a valid PDF document with an empty page in a ***text editor*** it's not exactly what I regard a ***commandline solution*** (as the OP asked for).

Comment: Great answer. Note you can echo this: `echo -n "%PDF-1.4..." > blank.pdf`

Answer (score 24):

If you have `convert` (an ImageMagick utility) installed, you could do this:

```
touch a.txt && convert a.txt -page Letter a.pdf
```

Comment: `convert` also has a `-size` option which you can use to set size of the output pdf.

Comment: You can also write `convert xc:none -page Letter a.pdf` without creating empty txt file.

Comment: @BartekChom's method seems to create an even blanker blank page. It produces a smaller file, with absolutely nothing selectable on it, and it doesn't trigger any `(null)` font errors.

Comment: @BartekChom I want that as a separate answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: I got `convert.im6: improper image header `a.txt' @ error/txt.c/ReadTXTImage/429.
convert.im6: no images defined `a.pdf' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3044.
`

Comment: Works for me with ImageMagick version: `6.7.2-7 2015-07-22 Q16`

Answer (score 19):

`echo .bp | groff -T pdf > t.pdf`

Brought to you by groff, the world's most underrated software.

Comment: I get `groff: can't find \`DESC' file` and `groff:fatal error: invalid device \`pdf'` with groff version 1.22.2 on CentOS 7.2.

Comment: Same message for me using `bash 4.1.2` running `groff 1.18.1.4`

Comment: @gla3dr Install the complete groff package not just groff-base.

Comment: `.bp` just stands for "break page", which is why this produces a 2 page document. To produce a 1 page document, just do the even simpler `echo | groff -T pdf > blank.pdf`.

Comment: very nice solution, but `echo .bp` should indeed be replaced by `echo`, just like @FaheemMitha said

Comment: example could also be expanded: `echo -e "Hello\n.bp\nWorld!" | groff -T pdf > hello.pdf`. But I agree that question asks for a blank page, so `echo | groff -T pdf > blank.pdf` fits best.

Answer (score 14):

You could use pdfTeX:

```
echo '\shipout\hbox{}\end' | pdftex
```

which produces a blank single-page `texput.pdf` of about 900 bytes, half of what ImageMagick uses.

This puts you at the mercy of the paper size default of your TeX installation, though. To set the size explicitly you can go to LaTeX instead:

```
echo '\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
      \begin{document}\shipout\hbox{}\end{document}' | pdflatex
```

---

Yet another option would be to use Ghostscript's PDF driver, though the handy `ps2pdf` script:

```
echo showpage | ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE=letter - blank.pdf
```

which is much quieter than TeX but produces less compact output (about 2300 bytes).

Comment: I use the variant `echo "" | ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE=a4 - blank.pdf`. This is slightly smaller, at 2200 bytes.

Comment: `echo '\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
      \begin{document}\shipout\hbox{}\end{document}' | pdflatex` creates `article.pdf`. Is it possible to have it create `blank.pdf` directly?

Comment: @FaheemMitha: Hmm, I would expect ps2pdf with an empty input to produce a PDF file containing zero pages -- but when I try there is indeed a page there. Wonder where that comes from ...

Comment: @Faheem: With Texlive at least, you can set the basename of the output file with `-jobname <basename>` on the command line.

Comment: Ah, yes, `-jobname`. That's the correct argument to pass to `pdflatex`.

Comment: What's the simplest way to modify these commands to produce a PDF with `n` pages for arbitrary `n`?

Comment: @FaheemMitha: Each `\shipout\hbox{}` or `showpage` produces one page. Both TeX and Postscript have looping constructs you could use, but it is probably _simpler_ to use the scripting language of your choice to duplicate the command an appropriate number of times.

Answer (score 5):

On the command line, you can also use the command `ps2pdf` to convert a PostScript file to PDF; for instance:

```
touch blank.ps && ps2pdf blank.ps blank.pdf
```

Answer (score 5):

If you care about efficiency, I advice to use `mutool`.

```bash
mutool create -o empty.pdf /dev/null
```

This generates a pdf file with an empty A4 (595 x 842 pts) page. To get letter size (792 x 612 pts), use

```bash
mutool create -o empty.pdf <(echo "%%MediaBox 0 0 792 612")
```

Frankly, efficiency might not matter in this particular case, but it is notable that `mutool` seems to offer better efficiency than any other tool mentioned here. This may be relevant in production contexts.

## Benchmark

We iterated each command 1000 times and got the following results.

| Rank | tool (package) | time (efficiency) | output file (A4) | file size | PDF version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `mutool` (MuPDF v1.18) | 0m7.850s | `empty-mutool.pdf` | 470 bytes | 1.7 |
| 2 | `convert` (ImageMagick v7.1) | 0m10.416s | `empty-convert.pdf` | 1912 bytes | 1.4 |
| 3 | `pdftex` (texlive-pdftex-bin vπ-2.6) | 1m3.898s | `empty-pdftex.pdf` | 934 bytes | 1.5 |
| 4 | `groff` (groff/gropdf v1.22.4) | 1m58.505s | `empty-groff.pdf` | 808 bytes | 1.4 |
| 5 | `ps2pdf` (ghostscript v9.54) | 2m20.843s | `empty-ps2pdf.pdf` | 2254 bytes | 1.4 |

```bash
#!/bin/bash
LIMIT=1000
echo -n "convert (imagemagick) "
time for I in $(seq ${LIMIT}); do
convert xc:none -page A4 empty-convert.pdf && echo -n "." || exit 1
done && echo -e "==[OK]==\n"

echo -n "mutool (mupdf) "
time for I in $(seq ${LIMIT}); do
mutool create -O decompress -o empty-mutool.pdf /dev/null && echo -n "." || exit 1
done && echo -e "==[OK]==\n"

echo -n "groff "
time for I in $(seq ${LIMIT}); do
echo | groff -T pdf > empty-groff.pdf && echo -n "." || exit 1
done && echo -e "==[OK]==\n"

echo -n "pdftex (texlive-pdftex-bin) "
time for I in $(seq ${LIMIT}); do
echo '\shipout\hbox{}\end' | pdftex -jobname empty-pdftex 1> /dev/null && echo -n "." || exit 1
done && echo -e "==[OK]==\n"
rm empty-pdftex.log # be careful

echo -n "ps2pdf (ghostscript) "
time for I in $(seq ${LIMIT}); do
echo | ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE=a4 - empty-ps2pdf.pdf && echo -n "." || exit 1
done && echo -e "==[OK]==\n"
```

Comment: Nice work on the timing and size comparisons. With mutool version 1.17.0 I get PDF version 1.4, though. OK, I see you are using 1.18.

Answer (score 4):

Last, not least, here is the Ghostscript way to create a PDF showing an empty page:

```
 gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o empty.pdf -c showpage
```

The page size will most likely be Letter. If you want A4, use this:

```
 gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o empty.pdf -g5950x8420 -c showpage
```

---

<sub>**Background:** the ***`-c`*** parameter can be followed by any valid PostScript string, which Ghostscript will try to interpret. And an empty page in PostScript is represented by this short code block:</sub>

```
%!PS
showpage
```

Comment: How do the values "5950x8420" translate to A4, which is 210x297 mm?

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to make a PDF with a blank page, is using `rst2pdf`:

```
echo -e '.. raw:: pdf\n\n   PageBreak' | rst2pdf -o blank.pdf
```

just echoing in a single space will not do, you'll end up with a PDF file without pages (which is not the same as an empty file).

Answer (score 1):

This will produce a PDF file of 1 blank page:

`gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o emptyOnePage.pdf -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=612 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=792 -c  1 {showpage} repeat`

Change the `1` to any larger number to produce more pages.

This will produce a PDF file of 64 *numbered* pages:

`gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o NumberPages64.pdf -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=612 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=792 -c  "/Times-Roman findfont 32 scalefont setfont /pagenum 0 def 64 {newpath 250 50 moveto (page ) /pagenum pagenum 1 add def show pagenum (    ) cvs show  showpage} repeat"`

Change the `64` to however many pages you want (`1` works, too).
`1000000` worked when I tried it - but I did *not* open *that* output in a document viewer!

Answer (score 1):

With qpdf

`qpdf -empty -- vide.pdf`

result file size is 315 bytes